# AngularJS ng- click with External link without controller?

Tags: angularjs

I need to redirect the external link while we click on the radio button.
Is any possible without use controller

Comment: Yes, just use raw javascript if you don't need to do any interaction with angularjs

Answer (score 3):

Use pure javascript

```
<input type="radio"class="two" onclick="location.href='http://example.com'"/>
```

Kindly refer my example in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/parthipans/d4jd3ap8/

Answer (score 2):

Using native javascript.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';"/>
```